# CSS multiple borders aren't changed in dynamic width

Tags: css, border

I written multiple borders using pseudo elements way of [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/).

```
<span class="something">
    label: <span id="count">20</span>
</span>
```

CSS style is like this:

```
.something {
    background-color: #B3B3B3;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.something:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 2px solid #FF6666;
}
```

[image]

It looks good. but if I changed count, it cause change width and inner border isn't changed like this:

[image]

You can see this demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/GVNBW/1/).
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you really need flexible width of element .something? if the element .something would have fixed width, the problem would be solved:

```
.something {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;

  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

HOWEVER

if you need flexible width, you should redraw the .something:before element after you increase the .something width. i updated jsfiddle for that - [check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/GVNBW/2/)

the `<div id="container">` is added only because jsFiddle does not support $(document) modifications.